# simple Java calculator without GUI

Tags: java, command-line-interface, calculator

I'm trying to make a  calculator which can workout an inputted sum.

Example:

I tried something like this...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calc {

String sum; 


     public static void main(String[]args){

            Scanner sum = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter a sum: ");

            double newsum = Integer.parseInt(sum);  

            sum.close();               

            System.out.println(newsum);

     }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code, so that we can know where you went wrong.

Comment: Rather than making your own, why not try what already exists? parboiled, for instance, has such a calculator example.

Comment: *"any ideas how I could do this?"*  Don't know where to start?  Go through [these tips](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html).

Comment: Sounds like you need a good book on Programming in Java that guides you about the Swing library. What have you tried out so far? Please post more details (and code as well) in your question.

Comment: As an aside, you might consider the [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).  It could evaluate that expression as a `String` and return a result.

Comment: Guys. He's having trouble writing a console app.  He's not using SWING. He's struggling with the basics as far as I can tell.

Comment: I hate to point out the obvious but: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+calculator+homework - I'm sure there's probably something in those that would help.

Answer (score 3):

After getting everything into a string expression, you can use the built in javascript engine to evaluate the expression.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Please enter an expression: ");
        String toEval = new Scanner(System.in).next();
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        System.out.println(jsEngine.eval(toEval));
    }
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that it may do *too* much, but almost zero coding, nice one.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks, I'll have a little play around with it and try it out!

Answer (score 1):

You could use ANTLR for that. You can find sample calculator [here](http://www.antlr.org/works/help/tutorial/calculator.html).

**EDIT**

If you use ANTLR you will be able to add more features in the future **very easily** e.g. usage of parenthesis, some calculation methods (e.g. round, sin, cos).

Comment: I don't think ANTLR is appropriate for someone struggling to write a calculator.

Comment: The biggest challenge with calculator is that * has higher precedence than + i.e. 1+2*3 is like 1+(2*3). What about things like: 1+2*3-5*5 or adding power symbol (^) etc. On the other hand I do not know all the requirements of you calculator. I would personally spend some time and investigate ANTLR. It provides really nice set of tutorials so it would be very beneficial for you mastering Java in the same time.

Comment: We don't know that he's implementing precedence.  ANTRL is a great tool. I just wouldn't recommend that a beginner add it to the mix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how advanced with java you are but if you are trying to do it for fun, learning and investigation for the best solution maybe it's worth considering a design patter: ie this design pattern: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/interpreter
at least for fun

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](http://www.beyondlinux.com/2011/08/07/3-method-to-evaluate-expressions/) good article with different expression evaluation tips. It also contains reference to *Jexel*, which is good enough in **math expressions**, here is a short example:

```
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
Expression func = jexl.createExpression("x1*x2-x3");
MapContext mc = new MapContext();
mc.set("x1", 5);
mc.set("x2", 3);
mc.set("x3", 2);
System.out.println(func.evaluate(mc));
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont work with brackets, and I haven't tested it, but a solution like this might work

```
for(int i = 0; i < equation.length; i++) {
    char c = equation.charAt(i);
    if(c == '*' || c == '/') {        // Operators with highest precedence
        double op1 = getNumBeforeIndex(i);
        double op2 = getNumAfterIndex(i, equation);
        double answer;

        switch(c) {                  // Perform sum
        case '*':
            answer = op1 * op2;
            break;
        case '/':
            answer = op1 / op2;
            break;
        }
    equation = replaceSumWithAnswer(i, equation, answer);
    }        
}
```

And then do the same with + and -.

For the 'getNumBeforeIndex' and 'getNumAfterIndex', you need to loop away from the given index, until you find a non-numeric character. You'll also have to remember to allow for decimal points and negative numbers.

The 'replaceSumWithAnswer' method will have to get the indexes for the the start of the first operand, and then the last index of the second operand, and then replace the substring with the answer.

Hopefully that might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is easy question, but the answer is little bit complicated. You cannot parse the expression like this without any assumption about **grammar** of the expression. Is it infix/postfix/prefix. Does it use brackets? Is addition commutatiove? Is multiplication left or right associative? What is the actual meaning of * and + signs?

There are dozens of decisions to be made while constructing calculator, hence the Java programming language does not have any out of the box evaluation support. If you wish to have operations with their standard meaning, then use some library. If you wish to have some non-standard behaviour, then write your own grammar. If you will use brackets, than **pull-push automaton** will be needed to implement it, probably in conjunction with **LL1 grammar**.

BUT, when you are asking this kind of question, I suppose that you are new to Java and programming at all. I would not advice you to try it, you need some basics from theory of automatons and grammars.

When I was learning myself Java, I also run into this problem and I have solved it by inputting the program as windows calculator. The program contained one register which aggregated the current result and after each operation the program queried user for the next one (you can do this also using very simple parser - but remember, the calculator will not recognize priorities of operators).